# Condition about equality between a function and his Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

What are the conditions about the equality between a function and his Fourier series?

In case of pointewise convergence of the series, I know that the series converges pointewise at the value $$\frac{f(x_+) + f(x_-)}{2}$$

But in the points of discontinuity, the function may not assume exactly that medium value, for example a function that is equal to $x^2$ in $(0,2\pi)$ and 0 in $x=2\pi$, in this case, in the discontinuity points, the series converges at a function that is not equal to the initial function. Maybe can I say the same that the series is equal to the initial function? Or not?
There are some conditions to know when the function is exactly equal to the series?

Answer (score 0):

NO, you don't know that the series converges pointwise to $(f(x_+)+f(x_-))/2$, without  some hypotheses on $f$.

When does the Fourier series of $f$ converge to $f$? Yes, there are conditions that guarantee this (note that continuity is not enough). There are many theorems regarding this, which you can find in any introductory text on Fourier series. Or in this modern ago online. I'm about to google "Fourier series convergence" - I predict that I will find *many* such results very easily.

Sure enough, I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series) in less time than it took  you to type your question.

Comment: In my example with $x^2$, the series converges to the function itself where the function is continuous and to $2\pi^2$ in his points of discontinuity. Now is the function equal to the series?

Comment: @user411485 You honestly can't figure out for yourself whether or not $2\pi^2=f(2\pi)$, given that $f(2\pi)=0$?

Comment: Sorry for existing

Comment: @user411485 Well sorry. But if you don't understand what it means to say two functions are equal it seems  like you're really not ready to be studying details of Fourier series.

Comment: Surely my question is stupid, but no one answered me before! I was just trying to understand if and how much the equality was necessary, ok they are obviously not equal (I was not sure because I thought that maybe a countable infinity was not a problem, but you've been really clear is a problem), can I conclude something else from this looking at the function like a vector written in a combination of the elements of the basis? Is somehow a problem?